# Why linux is a monolithic kernel, while you can load/unload modules (e.g. drivers)?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Hybrid- and Microkernels are flexible, in the way one can add any higher-level functionality as a module, is it not the same for linux kernels? Why then linux is called a monolithic?

Comment: Exact same question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806585/why-is-linux-called-a-monolithic-kernel